# use form for add and update data,how is that possible in extjs4?

Tags: forms, extjs, tree, extjs4, edit

i have a form panel and a tree panel
the form is used to add new users, the tree is used to show the list of users

what i want is to right click a node in my tree ,click edit (already can do that) then i have my data in the add form panel and be able to modify there and update my user

```
so basically use the same form for adding and updating
```

this is how im trying to do up to know
but its not working at all

i added a model to my tree,i used loadRecord(rec), but i dont know how to bind my tree data with the form fields!
tried adding displayfield with same name from my tree model!!

my tree model and store:

```
Ext.define('TreeModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        { name: 'text' },
        { name: 'id' }
    ]
});

window.ATreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
model: 'TreeModel',
root: Ext.decode(objt.TreeToJson()),
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax'
},
sorters: [{
    property: 'leaf',
    direction: 'ASC'
}, {
    property: 'text',
    direction: 'ASC'
}]
});
```

my tree menu:

```
var myContextMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
items: [{
    text: 'Edit',
    handler: function () {

        Ext.getCmp('addaform').getForm().loadRecord(rec);

    }
}
}]
```

my form:

```
Ext.define("Ext.app.Adduser", {
extend: "Ext.form.Panel",

title: 'Add user',
id : 'addform',
closable: true,
collapsible: true,
animCollapse: true,
draggable: true,
resizable: true,
margin: '5 5 5 5',
height: 400,
frame: true,
fieldDefaults: {
    labelAlign: 'top',
    msgTarget: 'side'
},
defaults: {
    anchor: '100%'
},
items: [{
    layout: 'column',
    border: false,
    items: [{
        padding: '5',
        columnWidth: .5,
        border: false,
        layout: 'anchor',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: ' Name',
            name: 'name',
            allowBlank: false,
            displayfield:'id',//
            anchor: '95%'
        }]
    }, {
        padding: '5',
        columnWidth: .5,
        border: false,
        layout: 'anchor',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'First name',
            name: 'fname',
            allowBlank: false,
            anchor: '95%'
        }, {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            fieldLabel: 'Profile',
            name: 'prof',
            anchor: '95%'
        }]
    }],

buttons: [{
    text: 'Save',
    handler: function () {
        this.up('form').getForm().submit
                        ({
                            url: 'AddData.ashx',
                            params: { action: 'add' },
                            success: function (form, action) 
                            {
                                Ext.MessageBox.show({ title: 'Success !',
                                                      msg: 'User added successfully<br />',
                                                      icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                                                      buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
                                                  }) }
}) }]
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your TreePanel uses a TreeStore which in turn has a Ext.data.Model, then when you right click on a node (say nodeA), you should be just able to do `form.loadRecord(nodeA)`, the API for [loadRecord is here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord)

If it's still not clear, I think [this blog post](http://blog.andrewrose.co.uk/2010/05/extjs-loading-grid-record-into-form.html) could help, it talks about loading a grid record into a form. I know it's not ExtJS 4, but the key functions are the same.

Ok, let me show this with a super simple example, hope it will help.

First we create the form that we want to display stuff in, note that the `renderTo` property is bound to a div inside my HTML, so you might need to change that. Also note that the `name` property of the textarea and textfield, they are the key for the loadRecord to work, **they have to match the `fields` defined in the model later.**

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
    renderTo : 'form-div',
    items : [{
        xtype : 'textarea',
        fieldLabel : 'label 1',
        name : 'name'           
    },{
        xtype : 'textfield',
        fieldLabel : 'label 2',
        name : 'age'
    }]
});
```

Next, we create the tree to display our data, we start by creating a simple model :

```
Ext.define('Person',{
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [{
        name : 'name', 
        type : 'string'
    },{
        name : 'age',
        type : 'int'
    }]
});
```

Then we create a TreeStore that uses that model and initialize it with some inline data:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
    model : 'Person',
    root : {
        expanded : true,
        children : [{
            name : 'John',
            age : 10,
            leaf : true
        },{
            name : 'Joe',
            age : 100,
            leaf : true
        }]
    }
});
```

Then we create the tree to display the data in the store. (Note that the nodes will show up as "undefined" because we are not using the default "text" property of a Node)

```
var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',{
    height : 300,
    width : 300,
    store : store,
    rootVisible : false,
    renderTo : 'tree-div',
    listeners : {
        itemclick : function(view, record){
            form.loadRecord(record);
        }
    }
});
```

Now, you should see a tree with two nodes both displayed as "undefined" on your page, as well as a Form with a textarea and a textfield. If you click on a node inside the tree, the form will display the name and age of the selected node.

Comment: thanks,i tried doing what u suggest after reading the links, it still very not clear for me! i updated my question with where i am right now